# 403 Forbidden only in some networks

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

[image]

I have a asp.net mvc site hosted under Azure. We are getting the 403 forbidden error on some of the networks. Our customers are banks they may have some restrictions. But not sure why it is not working for some URLS. The same URL when we accessed outside the network it is working fine.

Comment: Has someone configured an IP whitelist for the app service?

Comment: Is this URL based or after any number of items? If this can be from the bank network?

Comment: I have checked no ip restrictions in APP side or web.config level

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that there are IP Restrictions setting on your Azure WebApp. Azure webApp [IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) allow you to define a priority ordered allow/deny list of IP addresses that are allowed to access your app.

If there is no IP Restrictions setting on your Azure WebApp, please also check if there are [IP Restrictions in the  Web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/#configuration).

**Update:**

According to you console error information. **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"** error appearance, it seems that your data return wrong json format. I recommand that you could use the  console.log() to debug the error. it seems that it is **not the network** error. If possible, you could get the test data from your customer to reproduce and fix it.

Comment: If there was any IP restrictions it should be available for all requests right.The client was able to login to the application and was made some requests.It startes failing only on some requests . Correct me if am wrong?

Comment: I have checked no ip restrictions in APP side or web.config level

Comment: And according to the error information, it seems that get the wrong token.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth If you have IP restrictions for client, all of requests are block. According to you console error information.  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" error appearance, it seems that  your data return wrong json format. I recommand that you could use the console log to debug the error. it seems that it is not the network error. If possible, you could get the test data from your custom to reproduce it